# ReactJs Problem I am using react redux and I call login API using redux in redux actions only success action called but not reject and pendingwhy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

**user Actions**
Here is I am calling user login API but its direct called the success not request nor reject
this is my user actions file code

```
    LOGIN_USER_REJECT,
    LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
    LOGIN_USER_REQUEST
} from "../constants/Userconstants"
import axios from "axios"

export const LoginUser = (email, password) => {
    return async(dispatch) => {
        try {
            
            dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER_REQUEST })
            const config = {headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'}}
            
            const { data } = await axios.post('/api/v1/login', { email, password }, config)
            
            
            
            dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS, payload: data.user })
        } catch (error) {
            

            dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER_REJECT, payload : error.response.data.messag })
        }
    }
}
```

**user Reducer**
this is my reducer file I use constant which same in the user actions and also in the user Reducer

````
    LOGIN_USER_REJECT,
    LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
    LOGIN_USER_REQUEST
} from "../constants/Userconstants"

export const Login_user = (state = {user:{}} , action) =>{
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOGIN_USER_REQUEST:
            return {
                loading: true,
                user: {},
                isAuthenticated:false
            }
        case LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS:
            return {
                loading: false,
                user: action.payload,
                isAuthenticated:false,
                ...state
            }
        case LOGIN_USER_REJECT: 
            return {
                loading: false,
                isAuthenticated:false,
                error: action.payload,
                user:null
            }
        default:
            return {
                ...state
            }
    }
}```




my login  page 
This is my Login page where I called the LoginUser actions with the help of button
````

const Login = () => {

````
const dispatch = useDispatch()
const [email, setEmail] = useState("")
const [password, setPassword] = useState("")


const handleSubmit = async(e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
  
    dispatch(LoginUser(email , password))
    
    setEmail("")
    setPassword("")
    
} ```
````

I am fetching this API using redux but not called these two actions pending and reject I want to also called these two actions```